# Html Unit not being able to find content created by JS

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

I am using the JQuery UI datepicker plugin to dynamically change some page content.  I get HtmlUnit to click on the text input, which should make the datepicker popup appear.  However when I call `driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-month"))` I get an exception - it seems anything which is newly added to the DOM by JS does not become visible to HtmlUnit.

I'm not sure if there is any way around this, but it is worth noting when I use Chromedriver I don't have this problem - I am able to find the new elements.  Also the `getSource()` method only ever returns the original source code with HtmlUnit whereas with Chromedriver it returns the updated source.

Is there any way to support the JS using Html Unit?

Comment: I [edited the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17598646/revisions) to add a ..question.  Please review it carefully and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17598646/edit) as you see fit.

Comment: Are you starting your `HtmlUnitDriver` with a [`enableJavascript` flag set to `true`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html#HtmlUnitDriver%28boolean%29)?

Comment: Yes, I am starting it with the flag.

Comment: I've found HtmlUnit to be very awkward and fussy with javascript, so much so that it is not a good model for how real browsers behave. Instead, I've switched to testing against PhantomJS, which is a headless WebKit browser. Is that an option you could try?